Refresh of region in left column in apex oracle page
I have a page with left column side model. In this side, I have 2 fields with values comes from P0 page. I use v('P0_FIELD1') and v('P0_FIELD2') as source values. In body region, I have an interactive report that uses these values. I click on a button to open a modal window where I change the valçues from List of Value. After close the modal window, I refresh the interactive report and P0 fields, it works fine but I the refresh of region in left column doesn't work.
I am using apex 23.2. Any idea?
Tks
Ricardo


After close the modal window, I refresh the interactive report and P0 fields, it works fine

Great!

but I the refresh of region in left column doesn't work.

Did you explicitly refresh it? I'd expect that you should do the same for that left column, just as you did it for interactive report. Generally speaking, both modal window and its master page should have a Dialog Closed dynamic action - see it in dynamic actions tab, its "When" properties:

event: dialog closed
selection type: region
region: put left column region's name in here


Yes. I have: 1-> Event: dialog close; When: Region of IR; on True: Refresh region of IR 2 -> Event: dialog close; When: Region (left); on True: Refresh region (left). It doesn't work. I had tested at 2nd DA (when: region of IR) but it doesn't work as well

I resolved it. I created an Dynamic Action in Close Dialog with a javascript execution: location.reload(true).
Maybe it is not then better way, but it is working fine.

Just out of curiousity, what is the region type of that left column region ? Not all region types support partial page refresh and in that case a full page reload like you're doing is a possible solution. Another solution would be not to close the dialog but to do a redirect to the calling page which will reload the page.

The region is a static content with 2 simple fields. The idea is select the client and its project to see a lot of report and charts. This region shows what is selected. I created a button to change this selection using a modal window opened by this button.

A static content region cannot be refreshed. If by " simple field" you mean a page item... those cannot be refreshed either. Instead their value can be set by a dynamic action.
